# Stuck at the CLI starting screen after entering credentials

Tags: login, screen

I've been having this problem for a long time. After following a step-by-step guide on how to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox (and please don't tell me this is a VirtualBox topic because VirtualBox cannot help with this issue), but as soon as I finish everything, instead of getting the login screen, I get this little terminal thingy asking me to enter my "ubuntu login", and when I do, it asks for my password. When I enter both those in, nothing happens except that a dumb message pops up, and I attached the image bellow as a link. Please help. I don't know if it's just because I'm not tech savvy, but I really need an expert to help me.

[image: Link to image of my login screen]

[image: Link to image of login screen that I want]

Comment: Ubuntu 4.10 is really, really old.  It's from 17 years ago...  Can you try a newer one?  I'm not sure if that will fix your problem, but I would suggest that as a first step...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 4.10 Warty Warthog was the very first public release of Ubuntu and, as such, is very much out of support. If you absolutely must use this version of the operating system for testing or writing a retrospective review, you will want to reinstall via [the ISO](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/) and choose the "Full Desktop Install" option. If you choose "Minimalist Mode", then the graphical components will not be installed.

If you would like a more recent Desktop version of the OS, which will give you a more functional system, follow these steps:

1. Download [an Ubuntu Desktop ISO from the official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. In VirtualBox, create a new virtual machine, providing at least:

   - 1 CPU core
   - 4GB RAM
   - 25GB of storage space
3. Configure anything else the VM will need, such as networking, audio, and shared directories
4. Start the VM and let it boot into a Live session
5. Click "Install Ubuntu" and follow the steps

   <sub>**Note:** When asked about how you'd like to partition the VM, choose "Use Entire Disk". This will not affect your Windows installation at all.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful reply. I will try it.

Comment: I don't see a "Full Desktop Install" option anywhere. I pressed F1 for help, and then I pressed F3 for the different booting options. There was only "expert-server", "expert", and "typical." I tried the "typical" installation, but the problem persists. Is there any chance you could send me a screenshot of what the "Full Desktop Install" option looks like or where it is because I don't see it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you see is the shell and you want the graphical interface.

You will need the GUI server called xorg, a login management (gdm3) and a desktop environment (gnome) in order to have a graphical interface.

You can install these packages with:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop xorg gdm3
```

Then reboot.

Although I see you are using a really old version of ubuntu. I recommend you to use a recent version of ubuntu unless you have specific reason why you want to use that one.

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Here you can download the last version, that has already the graphical interface included, so you don't have to install it yourself.

Comment: The screenshot indicates "Starting GNOME Display Manager" which suggests the desktop packages are already installed

Comment: Then try to start the x server with the command: startx

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I'll give it a try. Many thanks!

Comment: It spits out yet another error: "sudo: apt: command not found"

Comment: Gives me another stupid, confusing error --> fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X Server ":0.0" when I type in "startx."